# what is the default batchSize in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo to fetch around 2M documents in one query, each document only contains three string fields. the query is just a simple find(), without any limit() or batchSize().

While iterating through the cursor, I noticed that the script waits for about 30~40seconds after processing around 25k documents.

So I am wondering does mongo return all the 2M results in one batch? what is the default batchSize() in pymongo?

Answer (score 27):

The cursor in MongoDB defaults to returning up to 101 documents or enough to get you to 1 MB. Calls to iterate thru the cursor after that pop up to 4MB. The number of documents returned will be a function of how big your documents are:

> **Cursor Batches**
>
> The MongoDB server returns the query results in batches. Batch size
>   will not exceed the maximum BSON document size. For most queries, the
>   first batch returns 101 documents or just enough documents to exceed 1
>   megabyte. Subsequent batch size is 4 megabytes. To override the
>   default size of the batch, see batchSize() and limit().
>
> For queries that include a sort operation without an index, the server
>   must load all the documents in memory to perform the sort and will
>   return all documents in the first batch.
>
> As you iterate through the cursor and reach the end of the returned
>   batch, if there are more results, cursor.next() will perform a getmore
>   operation to retrieve the next batch.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/

You can use the batch_size() method in pymongo on the cursor to override the default - however it won't go above 16 MB (the maximum BSON document size):

> **batch_size(batch_size)**
>
> Limits the number of documents returned in one batch. Each batch
>   requires a round trip to the server. It can be adjusted to optimize
>   performance and limit data transfer.
>
> Note
>
> batch_size can not override MongoDB’s internal limits on the amount of
>   data it will return to the client in a single batch (i.e if you set
>   batch size to 1,000,000,000, MongoDB will currently only return 4-16MB
>   of results per batch).
>
> Raises TypeError if batch_size is not an integer. Raises ValueError if
>   batch_size is less than 0. Raises InvalidOperation if this Cursor has
>   already been used. The last batch_size applied to this cursor takes
>   precedence.
>        Parameters :
>
> batch_size: The size of each batch of results requested.

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html

Comment: `batch_size: The size of each batch of results requested.`
Size of batch as in KBs, MBs or number of documents?

Comment: @akki The number of documents.

Comment: Is there a way to manually override the default limit on Mongo's side? I mean mongo's internal maximum batch size config.